# Error in CLion and can't find solution anywhere

Tags: cmake, c++17, clion

This is my first time using CLion so forgive me if I miss any details.  Below is an error I'm getting from CLion.  I've been using Clion for a semester for one of my courses and it has been working fine.  But now were working on a group project and I've to clone our project using CLion.  I had no issues cloning it or even pushing/pulling code, but I cannot run the project and almost everything shows up as an error. Here is the error below:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.2.1/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S C:\step2\Aquarium -B C:\step2\Aquarium\cmake-build-debug
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33520.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33520.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken

(Error starts here, below)

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.2.1/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: 'C:/step2/Aquarium/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-rb8fqn'
    
    Run Build Command(s): "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.2.1/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -v cmTC_79ec5
    [1/2] C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS  /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd -Zi /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir\ /FS -c C:\step2\Aquarium\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-rb8fqn\testCCompiler.c
    [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_79ec5.exe /implib:cmTC_79ec5.lib /pdb:cmTC_79ec5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    FAILED: cmTC_79ec5.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_79ec5.exe /implib:cmTC_79ec5.lib /pdb:cmTC_79ec5.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_79ec5.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Cannot get compiler information:
    Cannot load Visual C++ environment from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat:
    command [C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, /c, "call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 -vcvars_ver=14.37.32822 1>&2 && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.1\jbr\bin\java" -cp "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.1\lib\util_rt.jar" com.intellij.util.ReadEnv > C:\Users\lions\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-cmd-env-data.1983993835751009242.tmp || exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%"], exit code: 0

[Failed to reload]
```

I've been in contact with my professors as well as have messaged CLion support but nobody has been able to solve this issue

Comment: `This is my first time using CLion` Throw it away. Start your study with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Community. You already got it installed. Just run it.